# My node process doesn't end on my EC2 server

Tags: node.js

SO I made an EC-2 Server and I've installed node.js on it. Then, I connected it to port :3000. It was fine untill I noticed that the port was never closed. I had no idea it was still open and tried 'npm run start' multiple times. I just found out that it was alive so I got the PID through "lsof -i TCP:3000" and killed it using 'Kill -9 "PID#" and tried to run the port again. However, it gave me :

```
node:events:342
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000
 at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1306:16)
 at listenInCluster (node:net:1354:12)
 at Server.listen (node:net:1441:7)
 at Function.listen (/home/ec2-user/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
 at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/index.js:12:5)
 at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1109:14)
 at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1138:10)
 at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:989:32)
 at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:829:14)
 at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
 at emitErrorNT (node:net:1333:8)
 at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
code: 'EADDRINUSE',
errno: -98,
syscall: 'listen',
address: '::',
port: 3000
}
```

So I searched if the port was open again, and it was still open with a different PID. I tried killing it over and over, but it kept showing up with a differnt PID.

If there is something worng or unclear with my question please tell me, I jsut started fiddling with EC2 and all this server things, so I don't know which informations are further required to solve this.

Comment: Are you using any sort of process manager?

Comment: What is `scripts.start` set to `package.json`?

Comment: @Matt I have .json and .js files that allow the node to run on the EC2 server. The server runs just fine

Comment: @MuhtasimUlfatTanmoy I'm not sure put the only program I'm using is Putty and VS code

Comment: How you are stopping server? Is it ctrl+c or ctrl+z?
Add this, anywhere in the code `process.on('SIGINT', function () {
    console.warn("\nGracefully shutting down from SIGINT (Ctrl-C)\n");
    // some other closing procedures or any clean up should go here
    process.exit();
});`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!!! I typed

```
killall5 -9
```

and killed everything and it stopped!

Comment: That command looks like it has some typos. Can you check it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is the exact code that I typed